# MongoDB® Sharded packaged by Bitnami Setup authentication and connect from outside of docker

Tags: mongodb, bitnami

I am trying to setup bitnami mongodb sharded docker from https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb-sharded with docker-compose-multiple-shards.yml

```
1. How can i setup authentication to connect
2. How can i connect outside from docker
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Authentication should be enabled by default. The Docker Docker-compose will create by default the user `root` with password `password123`.

To change the root password, you can change the environment variables `MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD` in all primaries and `MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD` in all secondaries to the same value.

Then, you can connect to the `mongos` containers (mongodb-sharded and mongodb-sharded2) and create additional users as described in MongoDB documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster-with-keyfile-access-control/#create-the-user-administrator

For example:

```
$ docker-compose exec mongodb-sharded bash
$ mongo -u root -p my_secure_pass
> admin = db.getSiblingDB("admin")
> admin.createUser(
  {
    user: "fred",
    pwd: passwordPrompt(), // or cleartext password
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Regarding your second question, the docker-compose will configure by default `ports: ["27017:27017"]` on the mongos primary (mongodb-sharded), which means that port 27017 in your host will be forwarded to the MongoDB sharded cluster.

You can then, for example, connect your MongoDB clients to your Docker host using:

```
mongo --host dockerhost_ip --port 27017 -u root -p my_secure_pass
```